# Why my login form allowing users to login with correct USERNAME, but incorrect PASSWORD? (See detail)

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I've made a login form using PHP and MySQL. Now the problem is that when I enter correct username and password, it logins, but when I enter correct username and correct "password+ANY_OTHER_CHARACTER", it still logins. Why is it happening?

***For example:*** If the username and password stored in database are:

```
Username: username1
Password: 1213456
```

Then if I enter these credentials in login form, it logs me in.

But if I try following credentials:

```
Username: username1
Password: 1213456asdfjksdj
```

It still logs me INTO SAME account.

Why is it happening?

One more thing, it was working fine previously, but I've used some seesion variables and session_start() functions. I think the problem started after using session. Please help.

**My login PHP code is:**

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["cur_user_sess"]) && isset($_SESSION["cur_user_pass"]))
{
  header("Location: welcomehome.php");
}
?>
<?php
$a=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'onlinequiz');
if(isset ($_REQUEST['signup']))
{
$c=$_REQUEST['uname'];
$d=$_REQUEST['email'];
$e=$_REQUEST['phone'];
$f=$_REQUEST['pass'];
$h="INSERT INTO signup(Name, Email, Phone, Password) VALUES ('$c', '$d', '$e', '$f')";
$i= mysqli_query($a,$h);
if($i)
{
header("Location: login2.php");
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
}
?>
<?php
$a=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'onlinequiz');
if (isset ($_REQUEST['login']))
{
$c=$_POST['mail'];

$d=$_POST['pass'];

$e="SELECT * FROM signup WHERE Email='$c' and Password='$d'";
$f=mysqli_query($a,$e);
if(mysqli_num_rows($f)==1)
{
$_SESSION["cur_user_sess"]=$c;
$_SESSION["cur_user_pass"]=$d;
header ("Location: welcomehome.php");
}
else
{
$error2 = "Enter correct information";
}
}
?>
<?php
$mysql=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','onlinequiz');
$currentuser=$_SESSION["cur_user_sess"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE Email='$currentuser'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION["profilename"]=$row["Name"];
//$_SESSION["profilepoints"]=$row["Points"];
$_SESSION["profilephone"]=$row["Phone"];
?>
```

Comment: separate your code page by page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you destroy the session or unset the `curr_user_sess` and `curr_user_pass`?

```
<?php
session_destroy(); // Is Used To Destroy All Sessions

//Or

if(isset($_SESSION['curr_user_sess']))
unset($_SESSION['curr_user_sess']);  //Is Used To Destroy Specified Session
if(isset($_SESSION['curr_user_pass']))
unset($_SESSION['curr_user_pass']);
?>
```

Do this when logging out. If you don't, the session will stay set after you correctly login and you don't even get to the part where it checks the email and password you provided.

Comment: No, it's not that problem. I've already used session_destroy(); function.

Comment: @VikasKumar `session_destroy();` right after `session_start();` to confirm that it is not a session problem.

Comment: It was a problem with database. I used INT datatype for storing passwords. I changed it to VARCHAR and now problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

First, a few pointers.

$a, $b, $c? Stop doing that! Proper naming conventions! Your SQL query chould be "$query" for example, your MYSQLI connection could be "$dbh" or "$connection", etc. This makes code far easier to read through.

Second, you're dropping "unsanitized" values straight into a SQL query. Why is this bad? Because if someone enters the username `1' or '1' = '1`, they've just found out they can waltz into your entire system.

Passwords? Plaintext? You really want to encrypt that! [Here's a little article that will get you going in the right direction](http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/).

Next, using `$_REQUEST` is generally a bad idea for 2 reasons. First, basic security, and second? Code maintenance. Instead break it down into `$_POST` and `$_GET` so that it at least identifies your data source.

Last but not least, [try looking at this tutorial for PHP PDO. It's a far better way of handling DB interaction than Mysqli. More secure and less confusing, too.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

Try this instead of your existing test login and let me know if it works.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

# Basic data sanitization
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM signup "
     . "WHERE Email = '$mail' AND password = '$pass'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows == 1) {
echo "Logged in";
} else {
echo "Failed to sign in";
}
```

Comment: No. It doesn't even run now.

Comment: The problem is solved. Actually my code was right, but I used data type INT for storing passwords in database. I changed it to VARCHAR and it is working fine. Thanks by the way. Can you explain your second "pointer" in your answer here?

Comment: Basically, you're dropping user submitted data straight into a SQL query. This means they can enter a SQL query into your form field and your code will execute it for them. Potentially this will give them full access to your entire database.